# Change javascript id with PHP to match with Modal CSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a css modal for image zooming on click obtained from `http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp`. I am running a while loop where I am getting all the images required from the database. I want to make it work with this modal css. I have set a variable count with increment as `count++` and placed it in the HTML part. But the javascript is outside the while loop. How can I use it there to make it work?

HTML part with while loop

```
<?php while($faf = $prooq->fetch()){ extract($faf); $count++; ?>
        <div class="image-container"> <img id="myImg<?php echo $count; ?>" src="proofs/<?php echo $pr_image; ?>" alt="" width="230" height="150">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="img<?php echo $count; ?>">
            <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)</div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Javascript placed in footer

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Please help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for #myImg in your HTML, but this ID is not existent. Instead you have, f.e. #myImg1.

It's better to use classes in your markup (in my example "myThumb") and attach events on that elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myThumb" id="myImg1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="" width="230" height="150">
    <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)</div>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myThumb" id="myImg2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="" width="230" height="150">
    <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)</div>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myThumb" id="myImg3" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" alt="" width="230" height="150">
    <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)</div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Some additional information: just use one modal markup.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImg");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("myThumb");

    for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
        thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            console.log(modalImg);
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```